# Vaadin Table Object returns null, though it exists - modify toString()?

Tags: java, vaadin

I use a Vaadin table object and it works well (no Exeptions and it looks allright in the Browser).

But when I check for `!= null` or simply print it to console it actually returns `null` instead of an ID/hashCode, though it is initialized and working.

in test.java:

```
Table table = new Table();
System.out.println("table: " + table);
```

Console output:

```
>> table: null
```

I figured out, that the Vaadin Table class overrides the `toString()` of normal Java objects to a kind of alignemt (which is null by default here) for that table. So it doesn't return a hexCode as it should be normally (at least I guess so!?).

My question is: how to fix that behaviour, so that I can write proper test for similarity and `!= null`?
Is there a hexCode method that doesn't interfer whit the other/standard Java objects codes?

Comment: What do you mean by `write proper test for similarity and != null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) or if you really need to use toString you can override it:

```
    Table table = new Table(){
    final Long hexcode = new java.util.Random().nextLong();
        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return hexcode.toString();
        }
    };
    System.out.println("table: " + table);
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't normal to become a hex code from the tostring method. The `toString` method is to create a String which represents the object. If you do this:

```
if(table != null)
```

the `toString` method won't be called. Java only checks if there is an object in the variable called "table" or not. If you want to check if the table is empty you should use the method `isEmpty`. If you want the hexcode of an object, which is called hashcode, you should use this Method:`hashCode()`

More Informations to `toString` and `hashCode`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()